# Compare two different types of list

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have 2 different types of list and need to compare it.both list have GUID's.

First I will show you the error.

> Error  10  'System.Collections.Generic.List' does not contain a definition for 'Except' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Except TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable TSource>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable TSource>)' has some invalid arguments

My code

```
List<CarViewModel> _GetCarsBeforeMove = icarrepository
    .GetList(x => x.CarId.Equals(interlst.Car2Id) && x.ModelId.Equals(interlst.Model2Id))
    .Select(x => new CarViewModel
    {
        CarId = x.CardId, //This returns this type of Id's list 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001
    }).ToList();
```

I have another list,this list also have Guid's

```
List<Guid> _GetCarsAfterMove = new List<Guid>();
_GetCarsAfterMove .AddRange(interlst.IntLst); //List has values
```

Now, I wanted to compare above 2 Lists and get the difference

```
var MovedCars = _GetCarsAfterMove.Except(_GetCarsBeforeMove).ToList(); //Above error shows me here
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `Except` expects an `IEnumerable<Guid>`, not an `IEnumerable<CarViewModel>`.

Change the last line to:

```
var MovedCars = _GetCarsAfterMove.Except(_GetCarsBeforeMove.Select(c => c.CarId)).ToList();
```